# Saving relations in yii2 forms - how to avoid duplication in attributes?

Tags: php, yii2

I have Student model (id, name, school_id) and School model (id, name, ...)
The relation schema is:  school has many students, student can only have one school.

```
<?php
class School extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
/*.....*/
public function getStudents()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Student::className(), ['school_id' => 'id']);
}
/*.....*/
}
?>
```

Now I want to render checkboxes for each student on the School create form:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'students')->checkboxList(ArrayHelper::map($allStudents, 'id', 'name')) ?>
```

($model is School instance. For simplicity let's assume that there are not a lot of students - so checkboxes control is enough)

Now, if I want to add validation rule to allow max 5 students (using School::rules() method) - on form submit I get 
"Trying to set read-only attribute students"

Okay, that means that AR relations are readonly attributes in models.

But how I can use Yii2 activeForm and validations using rules then, without creation of another bogus attribute (student_ids) which won't be saved to db and will be used solely for validation purposes?

Is there a "right" way here? 
Thanks!

Comment: I've also been thinking about this problem, and making another model solely for the form. What solution did you come up with?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand it correctly, what u need is like u just want 5 student checkboxes shown in the school model.

In this case, perhaps u dont need to do the validation.

Just define another relation like:

```
public function getStudentsForSchool()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Student::className(), ['school_id' => 'id'],'limit'=>5);
}
```

So that every time u get the student list using this function, It will only get the top 5 records.